# Windows Mobile 5 Exception handling

Tags: windows-mobile

We're building a Windows Mobile 5 thin client using the .NET CF 2.0.  Throughout the app we are making network calls to the cloud.

What is the best way to handle the network connectivity exceptions that get thrown when connectivity is lost?  We're trying to avoid wrapping 100s of calls in try-catch statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its kinda funny cause you have the same problem with Thick clients on Windows CE as they've left out (or had at the time I was coding) one of the handy events to capture UI exceptions in the Compact Framework.

The way we ended up solving it (which was pretty straight forward as it was designed as a insanely configurable solution) was to push all "actions" through a single method. This is enabled us to place the exception handling in one place.

If you're just concerned about calls to the cloud is it not possible to push these through a single method? Or alternatively if the input / output is mostly identical a method that takes a delegate as a parameter? Perhaps even a generic delegate?

Comment: This is basically the route we were planning on taking if there was no other elegant solution being overlooked.  Thanks.

Comment: @JasonWatts/@Quibbblesome any code snippets ? or some more information ?